# scala: Create tuple from java?

Tags: java, scala, tuples

I must have missed something obvious, but how do
you create a scala-tuple in Java.

I have a scala interface that is implemented in java (for now)
and includes the return of a tuple, but how do I implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the class [`scala.Tuple1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Tuple1.html), `scala.Tuple2`, ..., `scala.Tuple22`.

http://codemonkeyism.com/tuples-scala-goodness/ explains it well:

> What are tuples? Tuples are containers for values. In Scala you create a Tuple with:
>
> ```
> scala> val t = (1,2)
> t: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
> ```
>
> which is syntactic sugar for
>
> ```
> scala> val t = new Tuple2(1,2)
> t: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
> ```
>
> as Tuples are plain classes in the Scala library. Tuples are of type `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, `Tuple3` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Just to signal the link above takes to a "404 Not Found" page.

Answer (score 12):

A tuple is only syntactic sugar for the class Tuple2:

```
new Tuple2<String, String>("foo", "bar");
```

will do the trick in Java.

```
scala> ("foo", "bar")
res0: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (foo,bar)

scala> new Tuple2[String, String]("foo", "bar")
res1: (String, String) = (foo,bar)

scala> ("foo", "bar").getClass.getName
res3: java.lang.String = scala.Tuple2
```

There are similar Tuple3 ... Tuple22 classes.